# how to effectively store data in react native snap carousel and access them inside carousel using data & renderItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**I want to store the data as an array in my carousel js file and access this data inside `<Carousel>` using `data={this.state.data}
renderItem={this.renderItem}`**

how can I do this

**I have 8 different images as the data in my code**

and this is how my present code is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

class TeamScroll extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
      <View style={{ transform: [{ rotate: '-14deg' }] }}>
      <Carousel
      inactiveSlideOpacity={0.6}
      inactiveSlideScale={0.65}
      firstItem={1}
      sliderWidth={width}
      itemWidth={width / 3} >
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logo-chepauk.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logo-dindigul.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logo-kanchi.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logo-karaikudi.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logo-kovai.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logomadurai.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logothiruvallur.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      <Image
      source={require('./Images/logotuti.png')}
      style={styles.logoStyle}  />
      </Carousel>
      </View>
      </View>
);
}
}
const styles = {
  logoStyle: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '14deg' }],
    width: width / 3,
    height: width / 3
    }
};
export default TeamScroll;
```

I want to use  `data={this.state.data}
renderItem={this.renderItem}` inside  and access these image data

and also I want to store these images in an array and use them

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const images = [
  require('./Images/logo-chepauk.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-dindigul.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-kanchi.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-karaikudi.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-kovai.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-logomadurai.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-logothiruvallur.png'),
  require('./Images/logo-logotuti.png'),
];

class TeamScroll extends Component {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Image
        source={item}
        style={styles.logoStyle}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ transform: [{ rotate: '-14deg' }] }}>
          <Carousel
            inactiveSlideOpacity={0.6}
            inactiveSlideScale={0.65}
            firstItem={1}
            sliderWidth={width}
            itemWidth={width / 3}
            data={images}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  logoStyle: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '14deg' }],
    width: width / 3,
    height: width / 3
    }
};

export default TeamScroll;
```

Go ahead and try this, I did not test it.

Comment: Thanks that is all what i need but can we add a name to the array item for using them in other js files

Comment: but the items are not getting displayed

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a reusable array, you can create another file called `images-file.js` and

```
import logo-chipauk from './Images/logo-chepauk.png'
... add other images the same way ...
import logo-logotuti from './Images/logo-logotuti.png'

export default images = [
   logo-chipauk,
   ... other images,
   logo-logotuti
];
```

Then, in any other file,

```
import images from 'image-file.js'
```

Comment: But this `import logo-chepauk from './Images/logo-chepauk.png';`  reults in unexpected token in eslint

Comment: What token is it referencing?

Comment: in the 1st line that is `import logo-chepauk from './Images/logo-chepauk.png';`   `-chepauk` is the one that it is referring   after not the chepauk in the path the other one beside from

Comment: The unexpected token error in eslint is pointing at something. Is it the i in import or the .png or .....?

Comment: maybe it doesn't like the `-`. Call it `logoChepauk` and see what happens.

Comment: yes its fine now but will  the path be taken correctly

Comment: Yep. That line is equal to `var logoChepauk = require('./Images/logo-chepauk.png');` You're just assigning what comes out of that `.png` to a name.

Comment: I know you're just looking to get your question answered, but sometimes you gotta look this stuff up. Answer: I accidentally named the default export when I hastily typed up that answer. Remove the name from the default export. Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export